# In computer network, does WiFi allows only one device transfer data at one time in a single channel

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

As far as I know, WiFi uses CSMA/CA to avoid collision, this protocol makes sure the Access Point (AP) allows only one device to transfer data at one time in a single channel (via RTS/CTS), does that mean the WiFi can actually transfer data from one device at a time? If so, all WiFis in a small area share the same medium, the air, do signal from different APs also collide and how does the real world avoid that? If not, where am I wrong?